# java - API response returning gibberish which is not gzip encoded

Tags: java, rest, api, gzip, encode

I am trying to "decode" the gibberish response from the API. Have confirmed that is not gzip encoded.

```
Request: 
GET https://<api>/automation-29522e405c/administrator/virtcir_492a439bac-0124-23482186 
Cookie: 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; Path=/; Max-Age=1800  
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=1.0, identity; q=0.5
Content-Type: application/compute-v3+json

Response: 
200 OK
Server: [nginx]
X-Transaction-Id: [1f307a45-60c7-4005-b371-73af56ecf6f8]
Content-Encoding: [gzip]
Connection: [keep-alive]
Vary: [Accept, Accept-Encoding]
Set-Cookie [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;Version=1;Max-Age=1799]
Content-Length: [404]
Date: [Wed, 24 Jan 2018 23:48:44 GMT]
Content-Type: [application/json]
ï¿½�������ï¿½QKoï¿½@ï¿½/>cï¿½]?ï¿½ï¿½(yÈ‡ï¿½ï¿½Dï¿½!ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½z0#ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Cï¿½H=ï¿½:3ï¿½kï¿½ßï¿½ï¿½Eï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Bï¿½zï¿½4ï¿½Pï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Æ™ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Iï¿½ï¿½ï¿½`ï¿½=Yï¿½ï¿½ï¿½J iRÔ ï¿½Xï¿½4ï¿½I:ï¿½bï¿½ï¿½`ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½;ï¿½[Dï¿½6ï¿½E6ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½cï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½uï¿½T
ï¿½"Mï¿½H7*Ú‹3ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½F;ï¿½ï¿½"ï¿½8KCï¿½&aZ`ï¿½Jï¿½Pï¿½bï¿½ï¿½\ï¿½ï¿½Zï¿½"ï¿½+,ï¿½Ç®;ï¿½Zvï¿½ï¿½@|Ó‚ï¿½Oï¿½ï¿½Iï¿½ï¿½ï¿½jì°§í‡º?
ï¿½Scï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Ojï¿½Íï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½`u)Tï¿½ï¿½Æï¿½cÝ‘Zs
zC,ï¿½_&ï¿½ï¿½Ã·;Â®qWï¿½Kï¿½Zï¿½tï¿½k&ï¿½xï¿½Ñ±{ï¿½ï¿½iï¿½afï¿½90ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½rï¿½P>ï¿½Mï¿½fï¿½ï¿½qï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½SÅ‹ï¿½2Wï¿½2ï¿½ï¿½1ï¿½ï¿½w#mqudï¿½+f}[Ý”ï¿½=Ã”Eqhï¿½ï¿½|ï¿½ï¿½fï¿½ï¿½e6  ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½-}Zï¿½ï¿½×Œï¿½ï¿½ï¿½��
```

This is my code that takes in the response from the API, checks if it is gzipped and returns a String which is in JSON format. It throws an Exception at the line **GZIPInputStream zippedInputStream =  new GZIPInputStream(inp);**

```
public static boolean isZipped(final byte[] compressed) {
    return (compressed[0] == (byte) (GZIPInputStream.GZIP_MAGIC)) && (compressed[1] == (byte) (GZIPInputStream.GZIP_MAGIC >> 8));
}

public String getResponseBody(Response response) throws IOException{
    String contentEncoding = response.getHeaders().getFirst("Content-Encoding");
    writeLog("Value of Content-encoding header " + contentEncoding);

    if(contentEncoding !=  null && contentEncoding.indexOf("gzip") != -1){
      writeLog("This is gzipped content  " );
      try {
          StringWriter responseBody = new StringWriter();
          PrintWriter responseWriter = new PrintWriter(responseBody);
          writeLog("Bytes are zipped = " + isZipped(response.getResponseBody().getBytes()));

          ByteArrayInputStream inp = new ByteArrayInputStream(response.getResponseBody().getBytes());
          GZIPInputStream zippedInputStream =  new GZIPInputStream(inp);
          BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(zippedInputStream, "UTF-8"));
          String line = null;
          while( (line =r.readLine()) != null){
            responseWriter.println(line);
          }
          writeLog(responseBody.toString());
          return responseBody.toString();
      } catch (Exception e) {
          writeLog(e);
      }
    }
    writeLog("The response is not zipped");
    return response.getResponseBody();
 }
```

Some of the Logging output.

```
Value of Content-encoding header gzip
This is gzipped content  
Bytes are zipped = false
java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format
  at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readHeader(GZIPInputStream.java:165)
  at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:79)
  at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:91)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
  at oracle.cloud9.qa.Method.run(Method.java:471)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have a feeling that the data is present but just not comprehendible. I have been searching for answers and tried a bunch but no success. It would be greatly appreciate if someone can take a look and point out any obvious issues and make suggestions so as to fix this.

Can add more information if needed too.

Sometimes, I get the right response

```
Request: 
GET https://<api>/automation-4110ff83c8/administrator/virtcir_576c0d077f-0124-233002191
Cookie: 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; Path=/; Max-Age=1800
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=1.0, identity; q=0.5
Content-Type: application/compute-v3+json


Response: 
200 OK
Server: [nginx]
X-Transaction-Id: [b0a42947-975d-4c80-9564-f6ccfefc4321]
Connection: [keep-alive]
Vary: [Accept]
Set-Cookie:[eyJpZGVudGl0eSI6IntcInJlYWxtXCI6XCJkZW4xNVwiLFwidmFsdWVcIjpcIntcXFwicmVhbG1cXFwiOlxcXCJkZW4xNVxcXCIsXFxcImN1c3RvbWVyXFxcIjpcXFwicm9vdFxcXCIsXFxcImV4cGlyZXNcXFwiOjEuNTE2ODM4NDI4NDM2NzEyRTksXFxcInVzZXJcXFwiOlxcXCIvcm9vdC9yb290XFxcIixcXFwiZ3JvdXBzXFxcIjpbXFxcIi9yb290XFxcIl0sXFxcImludGVybmFsXFxcIjpmYWxzZSxcXFwidXNlcl9pZFxcXCI6XFxcImI2ZjU1NmY2LTZlZTgtNDA4NS04Y2U0LWI5MjQ3ZDU4Zjg4NlxcXCIsXFxcImVudGl0eV90eXBlXFxcIjpcXFwidXNlclxcXCIsXFxcInNlc3Npb25fZXhwaXJlc1xcXCI6MS41MTY4NDc0Mjg0MzY2ODhFOX1cIixcInNpZ25hdHVyZVwiOlwiTUlpdVhIRzZIS1lmdEYwL2JVbU5rNmROVi8vem0yakVyU3R4ZUo4WkYwdVhpeHc2NXBWM3hMcjFTcTRBeE8rMkYvY2NyT2htQTluZlFqVCtodklLKzNNNjFnSXZNKy8wbGtjTnQ1VW10bzFnc0hVWjhVOTRrTGJPNEtoSHozUG1Ud3ZCUjkxdjR3SHpselVYejZnTjEvNFNMekZuWWZnYmV6VSsvL2pKTzlORFd5SGh2VmdiTGFyRFpYSkxtb29uVStjd3dSQU0xNnRBVWE3ejU3YnE5VzA3TVovRE1LMHNSamFmV0N3OVY2WTFWM21NeXhyY1N2YW8zbnl4VzR2blRVTU9rZFRRcTB6RExEZml4U1lmTFRIR1V5bW5JU3ZRUmdBMDUwUUU4RXV3VUVwUGFTcnRrdzhKdnJPQTVEVE1IajNyQkozRkRXOEtnbGdMUEhxQjRRPT1cIn0ifQ==;Version=1;Max-Age=1799]
Content-Length: [714]
Date: [Wed, 24 Jan 2018 23:30:28 GMT]
Content-Type: [application/json]
{"name":"/automation-4110ff83c8/administrator/virtcir_576c0d077f-0124-233002191","uri":"https://<api>/automation-4110ff83c8/administrator/virtcir_576c0d077f-0124-233002191","id":"991ba85a-29a7-40e9-8393-3b0463947299","referenceId":null,"region":"den15","gatewayId":"/automation-4110ff83c8/administrator/pgw_576c0d077f-0124-233002191","providerId":null,"type":"PUBLIC","bandwidthShapeName":"1Gbps","publicPrefixes":[],"flexFields":null,"orBgpAsn":7160,"customerBgpAsn":0,"providerState":"ACTIVE","bgpSessionState":"DOWN","lifeCycleState":"FAILED","created":1516836622525,"modified":1516836628338}
```

Comment: The string `ï¿½` (`0xEFBFBD`) is UTF-8 for `0xFFFD` or the "replacement character" used when an invalid code is detected.  SOMETHING is treating the incoming data as being UTF-8 encoded, but it's not obvious (to me) where this is happening.  Any chance the API is broken?

Comment: @JimGarrison, appreciate your insight. What do you mean by API is broken ? As in it is interpreting the request differently or something else?

Comment: As in the API is GZIPping the data but then sending it through a UTF-8 encode.  Also, what package/library is the `Response` object from? Where can I find Javadoc for it?

Comment: The Response object is an internal model which is a wrapper for ClientReponse  http://javadox.com/com.sun.jersey/jersey-client/1.8/com/sun/jersey/api/client/ClientResponse.html.

Comment: Look in your implementation of `getResponseBody()` to see if anything passes through `String` or `char[]` instead of being all `byte[]`.  That would do it.  Also, it pays to memorize `ï¿½` as a signal to look at your encoding :-)

Comment: passes through String or char[] as in to check if the response is a String or char[] ?

Comment: I mean if the input byte stream is ever converted to `String` or `char[]` and then that converted data is converted back to bytes (instead of passing the original byte stream through).

Comment: Apologize @JimGarrison can you please elaborate on your last comment? I see that, once the request is sent to get this information, the response (ClientResponse) is received. A "response.getEntity(String.class)" is done on it.

Comment: There is your issue.  You are converting to `String` at one point, which tries to interpret the incoming byte stream as UTF-8.  You must ensure that the bytes that were originally received for the response body are passed through untouched.

Comment: I see what you are saying. However, the confusing part is, I get the expected response 1 out of 5 or may be 10 times. Also, the code to modify that is not accessible.

Comment: Then there's a bug somewhere upstream that sometimes returns the bytes and sometimes the results of decoding.  You'll have to talk to whoever is responsible for the upstream code that wraps the response.

Comment: @JimGarrison. I think you are right. If you see the successful attempt that I posted, the response does not have **Content-Encoding: [gzip]** and **Accept-Encoding** in the Vary: [Accept, Accept-Encoding] headers.

Answer (score 2):

The way I fixed it is, by commenting out this line in the code where the response was received.

```
setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip;q=1.0, identity; q=0.5")
```

Hope this helps people who face this issue.